# Is it okay to have a blank root password for MySQL if port 3306 is not forwarded?

Tags: passwords, firewalls, mysql, server, port-forwarding

I'm running a PHP server that will use the root account to access the database. However, the server is behind a router and port 3306 is not port forwarded. Is it okay to have a blank password for the root account? I'm also blocking all incoming connections except ports 22 for SSH and 80 for HTTP.

Comment: Are you trolling?

Comment: Why is the port a factor in your consideration?

Comment: That's the default port for MySQL (I think). I was just saying that MySQL is not port forwarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principle of `defence in depth`  - You will want to put in place additional layers of protection to protect your data.

For your case, if an attacker manages to brute force your SSH password or manage to obtain your private key, he will be able to log into your mysql root account and obtain the data if the password is blank. However, if the password is set to a secure randomly generated password, then there is an additional layer of protection that will protect your data. He will have to brute force the sql account password as well.

Apart from SSH, it might also be possible to execute a buffer overflow attack on your web server on port 80 and pop a shell.

Comment: While this is true, they would also have access to my entire server, including the PHP script that contained the password. Likewise, if there was an attack through PHP, they would most likely have access to the database whether or not they had the password.

Comment: Also, a code injection vulnerability (eg: a buffer overflow) wouldn't be able to access your database if you have appropriate DB passwords (and OS file protections) set.

Comment: I am assuming that they brute force your user account password and not your root account password. Therefore, they will only have access to your home directory.

Try not to allow root logins to SSH as it increases the vector of attack.

Comment: @limbenjamin If they had my user password, they'd be able to use `sudo` to gain root access to anything else. The root account password is disabled.

Comment: Something else to note, I don't use SSH passwords. It only allows a key exchange, which is also password protected.

Comment: So there is already protection. For example, attacker steals your private key and your password for your private key. He manages to log into your account. He executes `sudo` and is prompted for your account password. Since he doesn't have it, he cannot get root access.

Comment: True. Is there any reason to believe a buffer overflow attack is a threat? I'm not very familiar with how exactly that works.

Comment: Best defence against buffer overflow is to patch your services regularly. It is very difficult to defend against unless you manually inspect every line of code in your web server. It does happen, https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/opov-1/Apache-Http-Server.html

Comment: Web server should ideally be separate from the database server. Only the former should store the database credentials